# Rails create failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So it seems that I must be doing this wrong.

```
Task.create :name => 'apples'
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<Task id: nil, name: "apples", task: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Then I thought, maybe my controller is wrong:

```
  def create
    Task.create(params[:task])
    redirect_to tasks_path, :flash => {:success => 'We have created the task.'}
  end
```

because it seems that my tests, using capybara, are failing - because they can't create a task.....

thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't save a Rails model to the database if it has a validation which fails, or a `before_save` callback which returns false